# Can switching from briefs to boxer shorts improve your fertility?

Tags: medical-science, biology, fertility, human-reproduction

[The advice](http://www.webmd.boots.com/fertility/features/increasing-sperm-count) to **wear boxer shorts instead of briefs** seems reasonable at first glance, since

> for testes to produce sufficient
>   quality and quantity of sperm, the
>   temperature of testes must be lower
>   than the core body temperature.

But is the temperature difference between boxers and briefs actually high enough to matter?

[This study from 1998](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9751347) suggests "**NO**":

> In our study there was no difference
>   in scrotal temperature depending on
>   underwear type. It is unlikely that
>   underwear type has a significant
>   effect on male fertility.

My question:

**Are there studies that support the claim that switching from briefs to boxer shorts (or other "loose" undergarments) can improve fertility?**

Comment: May I suggest you change the question from "Can boxer shorts improve fertility?" to "Do men's briefs reduce fertility?" to put the focus on the alleged problem. (If true, presumably "going commando", or joining a nudist group, would have a similar benefit.)

Comment: If they have to be lower than core body temperature (37 degrees C) how are fertility rates different in countries where the actual outside temperature is often close to or above normal body temperature. For instance, it's 40 degrees in New Delhi today. Also, note, India does not seem to have a problem with making people.

Comment: I agree with @Odd. Assuming that being naked is the norm, adding boxer briefs is unlikely to _improve_ fertility. Even assuming that briefs are the norm, would switching back to boxers undo any damage (which may or may not be happening anyway)? It is probably more clear to just ask "Do briefs reduce fertility?" or "Does your underwear impact your fertility?"

Comment: @Kibbee: I see your point which is interesting. But I still think that people in this regions have the same body temperature.

Comment: @Kibbee, (1) countries with maximum temperatures > 40°C do not maintain these temperatures all the time, (2) there may well be seasonal effects in male fertility, (3) sweat (and other techniques, such as bathing) can lower body temperatures below the ambient air temperatures.

Comment: Women find boxers sexier. Therefor, your chances of completing coitus are higher.  Which means your probability of fertilizing an egg are higher.  QED.

Comment: @Odd - Reworded my question. I'll stick to "briefs vs boxers" and leave "going commando" out, since I guess most people do wear underwear. But I'm not going to object if an answer includes it.

Comment: @chris: [citation needed]. :P

Comment: @Jon Purdy: http://mensthermalunderwear.net/Mens-Underwear-Boxers.html

Comment: @Kibbee: Human beings can regulate their temperature through sweating. There was however no evolutionary reason to develop the mechanism of sweating more in response to wearing tight underwear. There was a evolutionary reason to sweat more with hot outside temperatures.

Comment: Best to play it safe and go commando - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_commando.

Comment: @chris: The article you mention manages to not cite any references to back up any of the many claims it makes. Phrases like "Some women", "Study shows", "Some doctors", etc. already make the article suspect.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this Health Library article](http://healthlibrary.epnet.com/GetContent.aspx?token=d1db22f9-c4e0-4d22-bfa3-887872398b64&chunkiid=157009):

> A few studies have shown a decrease in
>   sperm concentration and motility when
>   subjects wore tight-fitting underwear
>   compared to loose-fitting underwear
>   (such as boxer shorts). It is worth
>   noting that most of these studies were
>   conducted on very small numbers of
>   subjects. One study published in the
>   Lancet included nine subjects; another
>   published in Reproductive Toxicology
>   studied only two subjects.
>
> However small, both of those studies
>   concluded that wearing tight-fitting
>   underwear does increase scrotal
>   temperature enough to significantly
>   reduce sperm count and motility.
>   Neither of these studies, though,
>   suggested that the deleterious effect
>   on sperm was long-lasting.
>
> One of the largest studies supporting
>   the claim was conducted on 50 men at
>   Leibig University in Germany. Its
>   results indicated that high scrotal
>   temperatures (defined as near body
>   core temperature) negatively affected
>   spermatogenesis (the development of
>   mature sperm cells). The German study,
>   published in Human Reproduction,
>   measured scrotal temperatures on men
>   wearing cotton jockey briefs, cotton
>   boxer shorts, or no underwear, and
>   compared the temperatures after the
>   men completed physical activity
>   (walking for 45 minutes on a
>   treadmill), and after they sat in a
>   fixed position for 45 minutes. The
>   study found significantly higher
>   scrotal temperatures while the
>   subjects wore jockey briefs versus
>   boxers, regardless of activity level,
>   and the lowest scrotal temperatures
>   when the subjects wore no
>   undergarments.

It lists references at the bottom of the article.

So it looks like there are studies that support the claim which answers your question. However, the numbers are significantly low to make a solid claim.