# Can using heated car seats reduce fertility?

Tags: road-vehicles, fertility

A family member warned me not to use heated car seats, since they cause infertility and cancer in both men and women.

I searched the internet for a source for his claims and I found this [Telegraph article from 2008 claiming might reduce fertility in men](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2632984/Heated-car-seats-could-reduce-male-fertility-say-scientists.html):

> Heated car seats could reduce male fertility, say scientists
>
> Men who use heated car seats could be unwittingly putting their fertility at risk, new research suggests.

Is this a correct interpretation of their source? Has any other research been conducted that confirms or refutes this?

Comment: Regarding the article - there is a big difference between "reducing fertility" and "Causing infertility" - the two are simply not the same thing at all.

Comment: @Norm: I edited the question to match the claim.

Comment: Note that the claim is very soft - it says it *could be* enough, in theory, not that the effect was measured in practice.

Comment: Surely it depends on how hot :)

Comment: @Sklivvz: Living in a climate where seat belts buckles can burn, I've had limited experience with heated car seats, but the ones I have seen have only had an on/off setting and a preset thermostat. Do they vary much in temperature?

Comment: @Oddthinking It was a joke...

Comment: @Oddthinking mine does. It has settings 0-4. 1 stops it from being freezing cold in winter. Thanks for the edit by the way.

Comment: Possibly related:  https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3793/can-switching-from-briefs-to-boxer-shorts-improve-your-fertility/4093#4093

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Telegraph article may be correct.

There was a study that showed that sitting on a heated car seat increases scrotal temperatures by about 0.5°C. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17919605

It is known that 'raised testicular temperature has a detrimental effect on mammalian spermatogenesis and the resultant spermatozoa' 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25456164

For optimal spermatogenesis to occur, testicular temperatures need to be maintained 2–4°C lower than core body temperature. http://www.rbmojournal.com/article/S1472-6483(14)00545-8/fulltext

So if somebody's scrotal temperature is an optimal 4°C below core then raising it by 0.5°C (by using a car seat warmer) probably won't affect fertility significantly. But since googled pictures of 'scrotal thermometer' do not inspire confidence in everyday use it is best to go along with a common sense advice to limit heated seat use to a minimum.

Comment: Link two and three point to the same article.